# SQL Server extend table and add date in a date range for every row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Id user
-------
1  A
2  B
```

I want to extend it and add date in a range for every row like below:

```
Id user date
------------------
1  A    20190101
1  A    20190102
2  B    20190101
2  B    20190102
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, and if not, then what relevance does the `server` tag have to your question?

Comment: Which dates are you looking to extend this to? A specific set of dates stored somewhere else? Past 30 days? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

A simple cross join with a calendar table should work here:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '20190101' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '20190102'
)

SELECT
    t.Id,
    t.user,
    d.dt AS date
FROM yourTable t
CROSS JOIN dates d;
```

Comment: The date range would be longer than a month and how could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join.  In SQL Server, this uses the `cross apply` syntax:

```
select t.*, v.dte
from t cross apply
     (values (convert(date, '2019-01-01')) (convert(date, '2019-01-02'))
     ) v(dte);
```

Comment: The date range would be longer than a month and how could I do?

Comment: @siyu, you can use a CTE to generate a wide date range according to your needs or load a calendar table with many past/future dates and use that directly in your query with `CROSS JOIN` and `WHERE BETWEEN`. See [this example](https://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/) for creating and loading a calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Tim’s response and I have an idea:

```
    WITH thedates AS
    (
        SELECT CAST(@startdate AS DATETIME) AS thedates
            UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,thedates)
        FROM thedates
        WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,thedates)<= CAST(@enddate AS DATETIME)
    )

    SELECT t.user_id,t.user_name,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),d.thedates,112)
    FROM [dbo].[test] t
    CROSS JOIN thedates d
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '2019-01-01', @ToDate DATE = '2019-01-02';

;WITH rs AS (SELECT @FromDate dt UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dt) FROM rs WHERE dt<@ToDate)
SELECT t.Id,t.[user],rs.dt AS [date]
FROM [YourTableName] t
CROSS APPLY rs 
ORDER BY t.[user],rs.dt
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0)
;
```